# Produce the infinite list [0, 1, -1, 2, -2, ... in Haskell

Tags: list, haskell, infinite, list-manipulation

So suppose we want to produce the list `[0, 1, -1, 2, -2, ...`in Haskell.

What is the most elegant way of accomplishing this?

I came up with this solution:

```
solution = [0] ++ foldr (\(a,b) c->a:b:c) [] zip [1..] $ map negate [1..]
```

But I am sure there must be a better way.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This seems like the kind of thing that comprehensions are made for:

```
solution = 0 : [y | x <- [1..], y <- [x, -x]]
```

Answer (score 12):

## With `iterate`

Perhaps a more elegant way to do this, is by using [**`iterate :: (a -> a) -> a -> [a]`**](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=iterate) with a function that generates each time the next item. For instance:

```
solution = iterate nxt 0
    where nxt i | i > 0 = -i
                | otherwise = 1-i
```

Or we can inline this with an `if`-`then`-`else`:

```
solution = iterate (\i -> if i > 0 then -i else 1-i) 0
```

Or we can convert the boolean to an integer, like @melpomene says, with `fromEnum`, and then use this to add `1` or `0` to the answer, so:

```
solution = iterate (\i -> fromEnum (i < 1)-i) 0
```

Which is more pointfree:

```
import Control.Monad(ap)

solution = iterate (ap subtract (fromEnum . (< 1))) 0
```

## With `(<**>)`

We can also use the `<**>` operator from applicate to produce each time the positive and negative variant of a number, like:

```
import Control.Applicative((<**>))

solution = 0 : ([1..] <**> [id, negate])
```

Comment: `iterate (\i -> fromEnum (i < 1) - i)`?

Comment: Isn't `flip (-)` `subtract`?

Comment: Excellent use of Applicative!

Comment: You also wouldn't need to import `Control.Applicative` if you used `<*>` instead of the flipped argument version.

Comment: You need to flipped version so that `id` and `negate` alternate; `[id, negate] <*> [1..]` applies `id` to every element of the other list, then applies `negate` to the same. Since the second list is infinite, you never get the negative numbers. (More briefly, `<**>` is not just `flip <*>`.)

Answer (score 4):

How about

```
concat (zipWith (\x y -> [x, y]) [0, -1 ..] [1 ..])
```

or

```
concat (transpose [[0, -1 ..], [1 ..]])
```

?

Answer (score 4):

How about:

```
tail $ [0..] >>= \x -> [x, -x]
```

On a moment's reflection, using `nub` instead of `tail` would be more elegant in my opinion.

Comment: `nub` is going to give you quadratic runtime and leak memory. It has to hold onto all of the earlier elements to check whether they have already occurred.

Comment: Right. I confused what `nub` does; I meant to remove only consecutive duplicates. And the reason I'd favor that was a semantic one.

Answer (score 4):

another primitive solution

```
alt = 0 : go 1
  where go n = n : -n : go (n+1)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also use [`concatMap`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:concatMap) instead of `foldr` here, and replace `map negate [1..]` with `[0, -1..]`:

```
solution = concatMap (\(a, b) -> [a, b]) $ zip [0, -1..] [1..]
```

If you want to use `negate` instead, then this is another option:

```
solution = concatMap (\(a, b) -> [a, b]) $ (zip . map negate) [0, 1..] [1..]
```

Answer (score 1):

Just because no one said it:

```
0 : concatMap (\x -> [x,-x]) [1..]
```

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party but this will do it as well

```
solution = [ (1 - 2 * (n `mod` 2)) * (n `div` 2) | n <- [1 .. ] ]
```